# How to select random element with same data-test ID?

Tags: cypress

Hi I am trying to automate a test of a page containing 100 books with details. All the books contains same data-test id. I want to know how to select the 10th book or 15th book.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I first recommend you change the page such that each book has an unique data-test id.
If the id-s are 1 to 100 it's easy to create a random selector.

```
cy.get(`[data-test="${randomId}"]`);
```

If somehow you can't change the data-test id's, you need to include more information about the structure of the page else we can't help you.